# PunBB 1.4 Extra/additional profile field

Tags: php, mysql, forum, punbb

I would like to add an extra field in user's profile and i want this field to be visible from the registration form.

I have registration approval enabled, so this field must be added first into the users' temporary table and then, after the approval, to be copied into the main "users" table, so the user will be registered.

How can i insert an extra field?

Any help will be much appreciated!